# Creating instance with unique name

Tags: java

I want to create a lot of instance in a loop but when ı try to String concatenation to generate unique name Java does not permit the operation.My opinion is here

```
    for (Classroom classTmp : classrooms)
        {
            String s = "sessionClassroom" + count;

            SessionClassroom s  = new SessionClassroom(classTmp);



        }
```

How can ı generate unique names to create SessionClassroom objects?Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're using `s` as the String variable and again as the SessionClassroom variable

Comment: That is impossible and doesn't really make any sense.  If you describe what and show what you're actually trying to accomplish by doing such a thing we could probably help show you how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a map to hold the sessions if you want to access them by name:

```
Map<String, ClassroomSession> classroomSessions = new TreeMap<String, ClassroomSession>();
int count = 0;
for (Classroom classTmp: classrooms) {
    count++;
    String name = "sessionClassroom" + count;
    SessionClassroom s  = new SessionClassroom(classTmp);
    classroomSessions.put(name, s);
}
```

Then to get access to sessionClassroom3, for instance:

```
classroomSessions.get("sessionClassroom3").doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because the objects are called the same:

```
String s = "sessionClassroom" + count;

SessionClassroom s  = new SessionClassroom(classTmp);
```

The problem is that they are both called `s`. The concatenate operation (`"sessionClassroom" + count`) is perfectly correct.

In order to solve this problem you should rename either `String s` or `SessionClassroom s` to use a different name. Example:

```
String s = "sessionClassroom" + count;

SessionClassroom sc  = new SessionClassroom(classTmp);
```

EDIT:
If what you want is having as many SessionClassroom values accessible from outside your for loop as the number of classrooms (count), then you should use a data structure like a List:

```
List<SessionClassroom> list = new ArrayList<SessionClassroom>();

for (Classroom classTmp : classrooms)
{
    String s = "sessionClassroom" + count;

    list.add(new SessionClassroom(classTmp));
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: sorry about my java knowledge but ı want to generate SessionClass object with variable name "s".I dont want to write again and again SessionClassroom sessionClassroom1,2,3,4  = new SessionClassroom(classTmp);

Comment: This doesn't address his problem. He wants to dynamically name the sessions based on the String, which AFAIK is not do-able.

Comment: You can change to almost whatever you want. You just have to make sure that the String variable and the SessionClassroom one have different names. If you want to keep `SessionClassroom s`, then you should renamed `String s` to something like e.g. `String str`. They cannot be called the same.

Comment: Ok, then if I understand what you mean, you should use an array.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to access the members, it's probably best to store it as an ArrayList.

Something like

```
ArrayList<SessionClassroom> lSessions = new ArrayList<SessionClassroom>();
```

then in the loop put

```
lSessions.add(new SessionClassroom(classTmp));
```

It depends a lot on how you want to access the sessions.